# Python 3.x - How to find the intersection of the sets of characters in two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I am trying to edit but I do not know how:

```
var1= 'ABC'
var2= 'DBC'
match= any(x in var1 for x in var2)
if any(x in var1 for x in var2):
    print("var1 in var2")
    print("The letters that are in var1 and var2 are", match)
else:
    print("No results.")
```

When I run that code I get these results that are useless for me:

```
var1 in var2
The letters that are in var1 and var2 are True
```

What I want the program to do is to:

```
var1 in var2
The letters that are in var1 and var2 are BC
```

If were to change var1 to ABD I want the result to be:

```
var1 in var2
The letters that are in var1 and var2 are BD
```

P.S. I also want it to print the letters in alphabetical order:
So I want the result to be like `The letters that are in var1 and var2 are BD`, and not  `The letters that are in var1 and var2 are DB`.

*Thank you very much.*
*Your sincerely.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var1= 'ABC'
var2= 'DBC'
match= [x for x in var1 if x in var2]
if match:
    print("var1 in var2")
    match_str = ''.join(sorted(match))
    print("The letters that are in var1 and var2 are %s." % match_str)
else:
    print("No results.")
```

This prints:

```
var1 in var2
The letters that are in var1 and var2 are BC.
```

Basically I'm using a list comprehension to find which elements are the same, checking if the list is non-empty with `if match`, sorting using the `sorted` function, and then concatenating each element into a single string with `''.join` (joining with empty string `''` because we don't want spaces between the letters).

Then, to avoid having commas in the output, I use `%` format syntax to insert the sorted characters into the output sentence.

Comment: I get invalid syntax in line 3 'for'

Comment: Sorry fixed the typo.

Comment: Thank you very much. Really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use set arithmetic to do this.

```
>>> var1 = 'ABC'
>>> var2 = 'DBC'
>>> ''.join(set(var1).intersection(set(var2)))
'CB'
```

Changing `var1`,

```
>>> var1 = 'ABD'
>>> ''.join(set(var1).intersection(set(var2)))
'BD'
```